# C/C++ SendInput extended ASCII

Tags: c++, key, simulate, sendinput

This Code should let press my Application the key '1' on my NumPad:

```
ctrlV[5].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
ctrlV[5].ki.wVk =0x61; //VK_NUMPAD1

ctrlV[6].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
ctrlV[6].ki.wVk =0x61;  //OR VK_NUMPAD1
ctrlV[6].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

SendInput(8, ctrlV, sizeof(INPUT));
```

It sends the key '1', although my NumLock is off.
So my question is:

"How to simulate a keypress from the Number Pad ?"

I tried `keyeventf_extendedkey;` too without luck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should be more specific. Where do you want to simulate this keypress? E.g. in a textfield of your webbrowser? 

Your question should contain code which actually compiles. It's easiert to help you then.

Comment: You need to combine both flags using OR: `KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP`

Comment: @R_Valdez I want to simulate it on a textbox ... this is just a small part of my code ... usually it holds 'alt' , presses '2' '1' '9' on the Number Pad , and releases 'alt' so we would get a ASCII char ' █ '

Comment: Maybe this will be usefull for you?
https://batchloaf.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/simulating-a-keystroke-in-win32-c-or-c-using-sendinput/

Comment: @AndrewKomiagin this 'combine' doesn't work :/   ctrlV[2].ki.dwFlags =  KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY|KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;